# Export .xcarchive in XCode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcarchive

How to create .xcarchive file in Xcode 6. In previous versions of Xcode we can directly export it from Organizer but in Xcode6 there is no option to export xcarchive file from Organizer.

**Xcode 5**

[image]

**Xcode 6 GM**

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just take the file from the finder, it's already on your file system:

In Xcode chose

- Windows -> Organizer
- On the left chose your app
- On the right chose the version
- Right click -> show in finder

Comment: On my machine, the path is ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives, with dated folders like /2015-07-23 and contentes are MyProjectName<datestamp>.xcarchive. Once unarchived, I expect to see the IPA file and APP.